# Why isn't hdf5 Dataset chunking make any difference on performance

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to compare performance impact of proper chunking of a hdf5 Dataset. Below is the result without chunking(in Jupyter Notebook). Loading `1000x1000` of data is about 20x slower than `100x100`.

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('datasets_test.h5', 'w')
dset = f.create_dataset('default', (50000, 10000))
%timeit dset[20000:21000, 5000:6000]
%timeit dset[20000:20100, 5000:5100]
```

> > 1.88 ms ± 6.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> >
> > 82.8 µs ± 773 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

I thought if I put the same Dataset into chunks each of which being `1000x1000`, I would see the perform of loading `1000x1000` being **less than** 20x slower because the `100x100` loading operation would load additional data due to the atomic property of the chunks. But the test results below don't support this:

```
dset_chunked = f.create_dataset('chunked', (50000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000))
%timeit dset[20000:21000, 5000:6000]
%timeit dset[20000:20100, 5000:5100]
```

> > 1.88 ms ± 12.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> >
> > 81.1 µs ± 794 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
> >     ​

Could you suggest where I got it wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify your explanation of the chunk size and number of chunks in relation to expected performance?

Comment: Please provide more details on how you are loading your data into dset[]. Also, don't forget you are loading a lot more data with the first method (1000x1000=10e6, requires 500 loops) vs (100x100=10e4, requires 50000 loops). Some of that time is writing to the drive (slowest operation on your computer)

Comment: @AMC, my current logic (probably faulty) is this: Even though `dset[20000:20100, 5000:5100]` only needs `100x100` data, it is still loads `1000x1000` as the chunk size is `1000x1000`. Therefore, the time it requires shouldn't be significantly more than `dset[20000:21000, 5000:6000]`, at least not as much more as in the contiguous memory scenario.